# Total area under any probability density function

Tags: density-function, proof

What's the name of the theorem that tells us that the total area under any probability density function, discrete or continuous, equals 1?

My stats book actually *defines* a PDF by requiring that
$$\sum_{x}f(x)=1\quad\text{or}\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=1$$

In other words, $f(x)$ is a PDF **only if** the above is true (along with a few other requirements).

Rather than using this as a definition, is it possible to *prove* that it's true for any PDF? If so, has it been done before? I'd like the name of the theorem/proof so I can reference it.

Comment: This is one of the Kolmogorov axioms of probability: see "Second Axiom" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms.  If you want a "proof," please stipulate what alternative axiomatization you are using.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. I would up vote it as an answer if you'd be so kind.

Comment: Thanks. However, even if that comment might have cleared things up for you--and I am glad if it did--it doesn't appear to answer the question you have asked: it cites no theorem or proof. Unless your question is clarified to indicate what axioms you wish to use for the proof--or perhaps changed to indicate that a set of axioms would be fine, too--it appears to be unanswerable.

Comment: The answer to your question (and implicit in @whuber 's comment, is "No". 

Just like you can't prove that a rectangle has four sides.

Comment: @PeterFlom In my opinion it is more complicated than a simple "no." Yes, by conventional standards and axioms, a rectangle is defined as a quadrilateral (under certain conditions), so you can't prove that it has 4 sides. However if you had a different system with different definitions and axioms (think about Euclid's 5th postulate, or the lack thereof), you might decide to define a rectangle as any figure with exactly four right angles. Then you could prove that it has four sides.

Comment: @TestSubject528491 OK; but I don't know of any equivalents of non-Euclidean geometry for probability (although it could easily be that there are some of which I am unaware; my training is more in data analysis than probability theory).

Comment: These are not unprovable, they are trivially provable.

Comment: @PeterFlom There might not be any out there in public, but you can always make your own. On one hand you can choose to define the exponential function $\exp(x)$ as the infinite series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ and then define the natural logarithm $\ln(x)$ as the functional inverse of $\exp(x)$. On the other hand, you could define $\ln(x)$ as the integral $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\,dt$ and then define $\exp(x)$ as the functional inverse. In the former, you could prove that $\ln(x)$ is the integral, whereas in the latter, it's a definition. Vice versa with $\exp(x)$ and the series.

Comment: I think the point @whuber makes is a good one which is that to answer the question we need to know which axioms are acceptable as the basis for the proof, if the statement is not to be accepted as a defining axiom itself.  Equivalent of the point made about defining a rectangle as an enclosed figure with four right angles (then you might be able to prove it has four sides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already well answered in comments. The requirement that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\; dx=1$ (together with $f(x)\ge 0\;\;\text{for all $x$}$) is part of the definition of a probability density function. And it must be so since that integral represents the *total probability*, and part of Kolmogorov's axioms for probability is that the total probability is always 1.

So a proof from those axioms is very short, it just consists in pointing out that the statement is part of the axioms (as above). Somebody will say that that is not really a *proof*, I guess that will depend on your exact definition of *proof*.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the name of the theorem ...

This requirement is imposed by the **norming axiom** of [probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), which holds that any probability measure has unit value ovver the sample space ---i.e., $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$.  The restriction on the density is then obtained by recognising that, for a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(\mathcal{A})) = \text{Pr} (\mathcal{A}) = \int \limits_\mathcal{A} f_X(x) dx.$$

It is worth noting that the "axioms" of probability are usually taken as the *starting place* for work in this field, and within this limited context, they are not derived from earlier results.  Within the usual probability framework these are not treated as results that you prove via theorems; you merely assert them as axioms.  If you would like to treat them this way then you will need to go deeper into the literature on measurement of uncertainty, and look at how the standard probability measure is derived from more primitive conditions/desiderata.  For example, [Jaynes (2003)](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf) derives the probability "axioms" as consequences of consistency requirements for measuring uncertainty.